# Android 10 open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-file

i am facing issue with pdf, i want to upload a pdf using Multipart but issue is when-ever i pass file path android 10 is giving me this error.

On ActivityResult:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String src = uri.getPath();
File file = new File(src);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userfile", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

Comment: once again ... uri is not a path to the file

Comment: ok thanks,  what should i do to get the path of the file

Comment: by create own file in private app storage, then copy stream pointed by uri to it ... asked multiple times - no, I will not show the code nor find the duplicated question

Comment: so we cannot pick files from files intent and upload to server?

Comment: ok is there any reference for **pick a file and upload to server using multipart body retrofit** please provide

Comment: Of course you can use the uri directly to upload the file to a server. You should do that too below 10. Allways.

Comment: yes, thats the main problem . Can you please help me with above android 10 file upload

Comment: Use the uri directly was the message.

Answer (score 2):

```
context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).?use{
      // read bytes and create requestbody here
}
```

Don't use RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"),file)  on api 29 and above because it will try to open inputsteam and an exception will be thrown.(if scoped storage enabled and the file isn't from media) Use array of bytes.

Comment: thanks bro please keep array of bytes way to upload please in java

Comment: just read the bytes from inputstream. There are a lot of examples in the internet how to do it.

Comment: use RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"),bytes)